# left join first match in hql

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql

```
select 
    schedulingpool.id,
    schedulingpool.allocationVersion,
    schedulingpool.tx.statusId,
    schedulingpool.name,
    schedulingpool.description,
    schedulingpool.schedulingPoolAddresses.name,
    schedulingpool.schedulingPoolAddresses.zip,
    schedulingpool.schedulingPoolAddresses.city,
    schedulingpool.schedulingPoolAddresses.countryId,
    schedulingpool.schedulingPoolAddresses.street,
    schedulingpool.statusId,
    schedulingpool.tx.name,
    schedulingpool.note1,
    schedulingpool.note2
from 
    com.xx.module.mm.jpa.SchedulingPool as schedulingpool 
left join schedulingpool.tx
left join schedulingpool.schedulingPoolAddresses
where schedulingpool.clientId = :clientId
     order by schedulingpool.id DESC
```

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference
>   collection [scheduling0_.id.schedulingPoolAddresses] with element
>   property reference [name]

A scheduling pool can have multiple addresses and when I execute the statement i get the exception.
Is there a way to just get the first address that matches and join it to prevent this exception?

Comment: If the result has multiple rows per schedulingpool because of the addresses it's ok for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use aliases

```
select 
    schedulingpool.id,
    schedulingpool.allocationVersion,
    tx.statusId,
    schedulingpool.name,
    schedulingpool.description,
    schedulingPoolAddresses.name,
    schedulingPoolAddresses.zip,
    schedulingPoolAddresses.city,
    schedulingPoolAddresses.countryId,
    schedulingPoolAddresses.street,
    schedulingpool.statusId,
    tx.name,
    schedulingpool.note1,
    schedulingpool.note2
from 
    com.xx.module.mm.jpa.SchedulingPool as schedulingpool 
left join schedulingpool.tx tx
left join schedulingpool.schedulingPoolAddresses schedulingPoolAddresses
where schedulingpool.clientId = :clientId
     order by schedulingpool.id DESC
```

And you need to have associations in the `SchedulingPool` class to the `schedulingPoolAddresses` and `tx`.